# Does GraphX support subgraph queries?

Tags: database, subgraph, spark-graphx, isomorphism

I have loaded a big graph and a small graph (which is to be my query) using the GraphX API and what I want to do it to check whether the big graph contains the query graph.I searched on the web about subgraph/graph queries with GraphX and I can't find anything about this. Does GraphX support this? If yes, does anyone know how it deals with the subgraph isomorphism problem: does it use some sort of indexing?

Comment: Perhaps you could try the mask operator. http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph@mask[VD2,ED2](Graph[VD2,ED2])(ClassTag[VD2],ClassTag[ED2]):Graph[VD,ED]

Answer (score 0):

GraphX does not support subgraph Isomorphism. Though there are some works on subgraph list in MapReduce.
[One VLDB 2014 paper](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/vol8/p974-lai.pdf) and [one SIGMOD 2014 paper](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~cuibin/Papers/2014-SIGMOD_subgraphlisting.pdf)

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be worthwhile to lift your content quality up

Answer (score 0):

GraphX can be converted to GraphFrame which supports subgraph queries.
https://graphframes.github.io
https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html#motif-finding